# Authorization has been denied for this request. WEB API and angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, unauthorized

this is my controller for WEB API.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using ShoppingCartAPINAngularJS.Models;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace ShoppingCartAPINAngularJS.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class CategoriesController : ApiController
{
    private ShoppingCartEntities db = new ShoppingCartEntities();

    // GET: api/Categories
    public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return db.Categories;
    }

    // GET: api/Categories/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Category))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCategory(int id)
    {
        Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(category);
    }

    // PUT: api/Categories/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutCategory(int id, Category category)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != category.CategoryID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CategoryExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Categories
    [ResponseType(typeof(Category))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCategory(Category category)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = category.CategoryID }, category);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Categories/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Category))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteCategory(int id)
    {
        Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Categories.Remove(category);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(category);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool CategoryExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Categories.Count(e => e.CategoryID == id) > 0;
    }
}
}
```

and for calling this

```
        // POST: api/Categories
    [ResponseType(typeof(Category))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCategory(Category category)
```

i am using this angular js controller.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

app.controller('categoryController', ['$http', '$location', 'authService', 'ngWEBAPISettings', categoryController]);

////categoryController.$inject = ['$location']; 

function categoryController($http, $location, authService, ngWEBAPISettings) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */

    //Creating headers for sending the authentication token along with the system.
    var authheaders = {};
    authheaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authService.getToken();

    //ForDate
    var d = new Date();

    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Category';
    ////debugger;

    ////Vadiable for Grid
    vm.Category = [];

    ////Vadiable for Adding
    vm.addCategory = {
        categoryID: 0,
        categoryName:"",
        CreatedOn:d.getDate(),
        UpdatedOn:d.getDate()
    };
////Vadiable for Editing
vm.editCategory = {};

vm.getCategory = function () {
    ////debugger;


    //For Grid
    $http.get(ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/Categories", { headers: authheaders })
    .then(function (respose) {
        //success
        ////debugger;
        angular.copy(respose.data, vm.Category);
        ////debugger;
        //var i = 2;
        ////debugger;
    }, function (response) {
        //failure
        ////debugger;
    }).finally(function () {
        ////debugger;
        //finally
    }
    );
}

vm.add = function ()
{
    ////authheaders.Content-Type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    debugger;

    $http.post(ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/Categories", vm.addCategory, { header: authheaders })
    .then(function (repose) {
        ////success
        debugger;

    }, function (response) {
        ////failure
        debugger;
    }).finally(function () {
        vm.addCategory = {};
    });
}

vm.edit = function (id) {
    ///debugger;
    alert(id);
    $('#btnSubmit').val('Update');
}
vm.delete = function (id) {
    ////debugger;
    alert(id);
}


activate();
function activate() { vm.getCategory(); }

}
})();
```

and this is the html file

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    app.controller('categoryController', ['$http', '$location', 'authService', 'ngWEBAPISettings', categoryController]);

    ////categoryController.$inject = ['$location']; 

    function categoryController($http, $location, authService, ngWEBAPISettings) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */

        //Creating headers for sending the authentication token along with the system.
        var authheaders = {};
        authheaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authService.getToken();

        //ForDate
        var d = new Date();

        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Category';
        ////debugger;

        ////Vadiable for Grid
        vm.Category = [];

        ////Vadiable for Adding
        vm.addCategory = {
            categoryID: 0,
            categoryName:"",
            CreatedOn:d.getDate(),
            UpdatedOn:d.getDate()
        };
    ////Vadiable for Editing
    vm.editCategory = {};

    vm.getCategory = function () {
        ////debugger;


        //For Grid
        $http.get(ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/Categories", { headers: authheaders })
        .then(function (respose) {
            //success
            ////debugger;
            angular.copy(respose.data, vm.Category);
            ////debugger;
            //var i = 2;
            ////debugger;
        }, function (response) {
            //failure
            ////debugger;
        }).finally(function () {
            ////debugger;
            //finally
        }
        );
    }

    vm.add = function ()
    {
        ////authheaders.Content-Type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        debugger;

        $http.post(ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/Categories", vm.addCategory, { header: authheaders })
        .then(function (repose) {
            ////success
            debugger;

        }, function (response) {
            ////failure
            debugger;
        }).finally(function () {
            vm.addCategory = {};
        });
    }

    vm.edit = function (id) {
        ///debugger;
        alert(id);
        $('#btnSubmit').val('Update');
    }
    vm.delete = function (id) {
        ////debugger;
        alert(id);
    }


    activate();
    function activate() { vm.getCategory(); }

}
})();
```

```html
<h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>
<div id="addModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Add Category</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Category Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control col-md-9" type="text" name="txtcategoryname" id="txtcategoryname" maxlength="200" ng-model="vm.addCategory.categoryName" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!vm.addCategory.categoryName"  ng-click="vm.add()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-10">
    <a href="" onclick="openAddModal()"><span class="fa fa-plus fa-200px">   </span> Add New Record</a>
 </div>
</div>
  <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Created On</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="cat in vm.Category">
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{cat.categoryName}}</td>
                                                      <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{cat.createdOn | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy' }}</td>
         <td>
             <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="vm.edit(cat.categoryID)" value="Edit" />
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="vm.delete(cat.categoryID)" value="Delete" />
           </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
           </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function openAddModal() {
    $('#addModal').modal('show');
    $('#btnSubmit').val('Add');
    }
    </script>
```

from which i am getting to data to save it on server it has grid and one modal that open ups when add the data and i am planning to use the same modal for editing.

the problem that i am getting is shown in the picture below
[image]

cors is also enabled

[cors is also enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iOgP.png) 
[image]

[cors is also enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iOgP.png)

[image]

after changing it from [Authorize] to [AllowAnonymous] it is saying bad request 400

Comment: just a kick, can be CORS?

Comment: How have you configured Authorization for the WebApi take a look at your configuration at start up

Comment: please check the screen shots am i doing anything wrong

Comment: Most of this looks fine. Make sure your `'Bearer ' + authService.getToken();` is getting set correctly. I can't see the value of the headers provided in any of the screen caps.

Comment: yes i am setting it at controller level                                                                                                  var authheaders = {};
        authheaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authService.getToken();

Comment: I would inspect in on a network level on dev tools to ensure proper Authorization data are being sent and proper result gets to the client